# Constrained $L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

The space $L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ admits an orthonormal basis:

$1, \sqrt{2} cos(2\pi n x), \sqrt{2} sin(2\pi n x), \quad n= 1,2,...$

What happens to $L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ if we add a constrain, say $u(x)=0 , x \in [0,\epsilon]$ for every function $u \in L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, with $\epsilon$ a small positive number?

Clearly the above trigonometric basis, can not be a basis for the new constrained space. So what is a new basis for this space ? Is the a rigorous way to determine the new basis of the constrained space ?

Also, it is clear that the dimensionality of the space is still infinite. But the space has changed, so is there any notion that can capture this change ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The condition $u(0)=0$ makes no sense for an element from $L^2([0,1],\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @MartinVäth Why is that so ?

Comment: The elements of the space are equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: So I guess you say the space does not 'see' such a constrain. Do you see any way to make my statement work ?

Comment: Well, as @Martin Väth pointed out, such constraints are not meaningful in $L^2$. If you really want to have something like that, you can choose equivalence classes of your basis that fulfill any number of these conditions as long as they're on null sets, but one-point sets are null sets. The space itself does in fact not change.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question and I think it now makes sense.

Comment: In the edited form, if $\varepsilon>0$ can depend on $u$, you do not get a **closed** subspace of $L_2$. In fact, your subspace is dense in $L_2$.

Comment: For an arbitrary closed subspace of $L_2$, the only “generic” algorithm to obtain an orthonormal basis is Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Thanks @MartinVäth

Comment: @kade Can you explain a little bit more your proposal, maybe in a an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is in response to your comment and not an answer to the edited but rather the original question. In fact I am not yet sure about the answer to that. Nevertheless, I hope this is helpful to you.

Recall the construction of the Lebesgue space: $$ L^2([0, 1]) = \mathcal{L}^2([0,1]) / N $$where $\mathcal{L}^2([0,1])$ is the space of all square-integrable functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $N=\{f=0 \, \text{a. e.}\}$. This means that elements in $L^2$ are equivalence classes of functions and thus, two functions are called equal if they differ only on a set of measure zero. In other words, assigning a value at a certain point is not something that's "interesting" or meaningful. You can do this if you really want to but it doesn't change much; say you want the set of all $[u] \in L^2([0,1])$ with $u(0)=0$ (where we identify $u$ as an $\mathcal{L}^2$-function and $[u]$ as the corresponding equivalence class). Then clearly this is a subset of $L^2([0,1])$. On the other hand we can realise this by choosing a representative for every $[u] \in L^2([0,1])$ such that $u(0)=0$, giving us the other subset relation. Hence they are equal and you can choose the same basis (by choosing appropriate equivalence class representatives that you need).

Answer (score 1):

One orthonormal basis of the subspace $M$ where $u=u\chi_{(\epsilon,1]}$ consists of functions that vanish on $[0,\epsilon]$ and equal the following on $(\epsilon,1]$:
$$
       c_n(x)=C_n\cos(2n\pi (x-\epsilon)/(1-\epsilon)),\;\; n\ge 0, \\
       s_n(x)=D_n\sin(2n\pi (x-\epsilon)/(1-\epsilon)),\;\; n \ge 1.
$$
The constants $C_n,D_n$ are chosen so that $\|c_n\|=1$ and $\|d_n\|=1$.